# What is the code string "array.IndexOf "?

Tags: c#, arrays

Typing the string "array.IndexOf", what exactly happens in the program? What is it for?
Here's the code.

```
int[] ArrayDiInteri = { 1, 3, 2, 6, 5 };



        var Lunghezza = ArrayDiInteri.Length;
        var index = Array.IndexOf(ArrayDiInteri, 22);
```

Comment: Are you asking for the documentation?

Comment: Such work has that code?

In the program what happens?

Comment: What part of the documentation was unclear? You are looking for the index of 22 in the array, because  there is no 22 the method returns -1. The index is between 0(first) and array.Length-1(last).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Array.IndexOf`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.indexof%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) returns the index (position) of an object within an array.

In your code, you are looking to find where the number `22` appears in the `ArrayDiInteri` array. In this case, the number 22 does not appear, so `index` will be set to `-1`, meaning it was not found.